# Restful service and local database Android

Tags: android, rest

I develop an android mobile application and I have create a restful Api, with this  [tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123). But in this way, the data appear only when the device is connected to Internet. I want the data to be existed and without internet connection. Should I create a local database or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems right from my point of view as it mostly possible that you must be fetching more data from server. So going with sharedpreference and internal storage are not recommended.

1. You can store the data locally first time when you fetch data from the internet. And when net is available, you fetch the data using rest api, that time you update the existing records and if any record is not present then you may insert that record as a new record so that you will have updated data. When internet connection is not there, you can access the data from the db and display it.
2. Sqlite is the better option for it. It is a light weight db system used in mobile platforms. If you know then it's alright else you may think to look this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You have three ways to cache json data on your smartphone

1. Save json as simple file: `todos.json`
2. Save json as String using `SharedPreferences`
3. Save json as String or binary data in database like Sqlite. Request Url could be `ID`.

Which method do you take depends on how large your data is. Like *Android Killer* I prefer Sqlite, since it is realy elegant way to manage application data.

---

You could implement all three methods and compare them. Also you will learn a lot about `FileIO`, `SharedPreferences` and `SqLite`.

Example pseudo code:

```
public String loadData(String url){

    Cache cache = new FileCache(); // new SqLiteCache() or new SharedPreferencesCache()

    String json = cache.get(url);        
    if(json == null){
        cache.put(url, json = MyNetworkUtil.loadJSON(url));
    }

    return json;
}
```